# SQL query to join table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with SQL.I need to join 2 tables and fetch particular information. Below is the sql/scenario for reference.

**Input:**
**Sql1-**

```
select distinct schema,tablename,tbl_cmmt as tabledescription 
from test.a
where tbl_cmmt is not null
and
schema is not null
```

**Input data:**

**schema,tablename,tbl_cmmt**

test,sample,test table
test1,sample1,test table 2

**Sql2-**

```
select schema,table,description from test_descr
join test_class on test_descr.objoid = test_class.oid
join test_namespace on test_class.relnamespace = test_namespace.oid
where kind ='r'
```

**Input data:**

**schema, table, description**

test, sample, table
test5, abc , not in use

Output :
I want to perform left join on these two sql and fetch all the data from sql1 along with one extra field that is description from sql2.Keys on both tables are schema and table.

**Output data**

**schema, table, tbl_cmmt, description**

test, sample, test table, table
test1, sample1, test table 2, NULL

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Please don't tag desktop tools unless the question is specifically about the tool.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to use your current queries as CTEs (or subqueries) and the join them on common columns:

```
with
query_1 as
  (select distinct schema,tablename,tbl_cmmt as tabledescription 
   from test.a
   where tbl_cmmt is not null
     and schema is not null
  ),
query_2 as
  (select schema,table,description 
   from test_descr
      join test_class on test_descr.objoid = test_class.oid
      join test_namespace on test_class.relnamespace = test_namespace.oid
   where kind ='r'
  )
select a.*, b.description
from query_1 a join query_2 b on a.schema = b.schema and a.tablename = b.table;
```